# Emacs Lisp: How to activate window of mouse event?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Having an event from a mouse click: How to activate the window where the event occured?

As I want to insert some text at the position of the mouse event, I use `(goto-char (nth 1 (event-start event)))`.

But in case the mouse event occured in another window than the active one, what is the appropriate way to first switch to that other window?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you do

```
(posn-set-point (event-end event))
```

Comment: In my case of dragging-and-dropping a file on the buffer, this command on event-end leads to the error _Position not in text area of window_ (as event-end contains the file path). `(posn-set-point (event-start event))` works fine, though. Thank you!

Comment: Hmm... I suggest you `M-x report-emacs-bug` about your problem with `(posn-set-point (event-end event))`.  Maybe it's the correct behavior, but it sounds like it's a bug.